# How do I open URLs, PDFs, etc. with the default apps?

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-xe5

I am developing an Android application with Delphi XE5, and I would like to know how I can open a URL in the default browser, and a PDF file with the default reader.
Developing for Windows, I used `ShellExecute`, but for Android and iOS what should I use?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For these kind pf task you can use the [`Intent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) class which is represented in Delphi by the `JIntent` interface.

Try these samples

## Open a URL

```
uses
  Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText,
  FMX.Helpers.Android;


procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Intent: JIntent;
begin
  Intent := TJIntent.Create;
  Intent.setAction(TJIntent.JavaClass.ACTION_VIEW);
  Intent.setData(StrToJURI('http://www.google.com'));
  SharedActivity.startActivity(Intent);
end;
```

## Open a PDF File

```
uses
  Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText,
  Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes,
  FMX.Helpers.Android;


procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Intent: JIntent;
begin
  Intent := TJIntent.Create;
  Intent.setAction(TJIntent.JavaClass.ACTION_VIEW);
  Intent.setDataAndType(StrToJURI('filepath'),  StringToJString('application/pdf'));
  SharedActivity.startActivity(Intent);
end;
```

Comment: Are there any wrappers for this that work on all platforms? For simple default actions shouldn't be too difficult to write one, but I wonder if there is any existing effort to create it.

Comment: @LeonardoHerrera If there is such a thing, it's not part of FMX.

Comment: @LeonardoHerrera: It wouldn't be difficult. I don't do iOS or OSX, but I have a version of both of these that now works on Android, Win32, and Win64; based on Rodrigo's code here to start, it took about 10 minutes to write and another 20 to test.

Comment: @RRUZ I use these codes but in android when call these functions app crash

Comment: If u use XE6 to up use Androidapi.Helpers instead of FMX.Helpers.Android

Answer (score 1):

n00b here can't work out how to add a comment to the set of comments already posted against the previous answer, but I use this, which is another variation on the theme, using constructor parameters:

```
procedure LaunchURL(const URL: string);
var
  Intent: JIntent;
begin
  Intent := TJIntent.JavaClass.init(TJIntent.JavaClass.ACTION_VIEW,
    TJnet_Uri.JavaClass.parse(StringToJString(URL)));
  SharedActivity.startActivity(Intent);
end;
```