# How I can open an URL at the default browser on the IOS under Delphi XE5

Tags: ios, delphi

I have Delphi application under iOS and I need to open a URL at default browser.

I was trying to find any kind of open or ShellExecute for iOS at the Delphi help, but no success.

I found this article for Android : [How do I open URLs, PDFs, etc. with the default apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18873699/how-do-i-open-urls-pdfs-etc-with-the-default-apps/18877904#18877904) and there is mentioned at the comments that there is no universal function.

I don't want to embed browser and open the site there .. I want to open a file at default browser outside the app.

Thanks.

Comment: Briliant, thank you. That was the solution.

Comment: I wrote an unit that handled iOS and Android: http://pjstrnad.com/opening-url-separated-browser-delphi-xe5/