# How to open playstore and direct to my apps page

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

i have android application created with delphi firemonkey and i want my apps open play store and direct to my apps page when i hit some button

```
  unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
//open playstore and direct to my apps page
end;

end.
```

Comment: You can take this as a hint https://stackoverflow.com/q/18873699/8041231

Comment: What have you tried until now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Intent := TJIntent.Create;
Intent.setAction(TJIntent.JavaClass.ACTION_VIEW);
Intent.setData(StrToJURI('market://details?id=PACKAGE_NAME'));
SharedActivity.startActivity(Intent);
```

Where PACKAGE_NAME is the your app's package that you registered on the playstore.
For example com.mypackage.myapp

Comment: Glad to help you